# Regex to omit curly braces

Tags: regex, vba, vbscript

Currently my regex in VBA captures everything in the curly braces (including the curly  braces):

`Pattern = "\{\w*\}"`

Is there away to omit the curly braces at regex level?

so {Computer1}{Computer2}

becomes Computer1
Computer2

Full code below:

```
Dim RegEx As Object
Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With RegEx
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "\{\w*\}"
End With
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot `Replace()` the braces, perhaps replacing the opening ones with a space? But perhaps you are studying regex..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regex flavors that support lookbehinds, you can do:

```
(?<={)\w*(?=})
```

This matches only the contents of the braces. Note that to avoid returning empty strings, you would change the `*` to a `+`

But VBscript does not support lookbehind.

Instead, you can use parentheses to capture the content to Group 1:

```
{(\w+)}
```

Here is code to look at it, generated by RegexBuddy (can't comment as I don't use VBScript):

```
Dim myRegexp, contentOfBraces, myMatches, myMatch As Match
Dim myRegexp As RegExp
Set myRegexp = New RegExp
myRegexp.Pattern = "{(\w+)}"
Set myMatches = myRegexp.Execute(SubjectString)
If myMatches.Count >= 1 Then
    Set myMatch = myMatches(0)
    If myMatch.SubMatches.Count >= 1 Then
        contentOfBraces = myMatch.SubMatches(1-1)
    Else
        contentOfBraces = ""
    End If
Else
    contentOfBraces = ""
End If
```